# net::ERR CONTENT LENGTH MISMATCH in Chrome with Jboss WildFly 8.2

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, http, jboss, wildfly-8

I have JBoss wildFly 8.2 Up & Running on a windows machine with my war file deployed.
but my web page not able to load JS file and it shows error message in the web console  as follows:-

```
"Failed to load resource: net:: ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH"
```

I dig into the issue and found that server not able to load actual file size.
my js file is about to 90kb but server load 18kb and failed to load js file.

how to resolve this issue.
is this a Jboss configuration issue or Chrome issue.
please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is related to jboss. I had the same issue of "net:: ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH" when I was receiving a huge response in an ajax callback. It was working absolutely fine on Firefox and IE but the console error was there on chrome. Because of this the response was not loading on the UI. After further research I got to know, that Chrome was throwing this error for a special character i.e. "Æ" which was part of my json response body content. However, IE and Firefox were not having any complaint about this.

I corrected the DB value and removed the above special character from the server end. Everything started working fine on chrome as well.

My suggestion to check the body response you are sending from server end. It could be server side fix.

Regards,

[Manoj](http://www.gitarani.com/classified.htm?classifiedTypeId=5)